# Why didn't Peter look for a medical help when he was bitten by a spider?

Tags: marvel, spider-man, spider-man-2002

In [Spider-Man (2002)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider-Man_(2002_film)), we can see that his bitten hand is very swollen and he was feeling bad, to the point of losing his consciousness.

[image]

**Why didn't he call an ambulance or something? Didn't he realize that the spider might be venomous?**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/221982.Spider_Man) indicates that like many [dirt-poor people in America](http://time.com/money/3611885/healthcare-costs-insurance-delaying-care/), he was trying to save a buck and hoped that it would just get better on its own.

> ***He'd been an idiot, a total idiot. Trying to save Aunt May and Uncle
> Ben a few bucks on a doctor,** when he'd obviously been poisoned by that
> . . . that stupid, stupid spider. Well, enough was already way too
> much. He was going to standup, throw open the door, call down to Aunt
> May and Uncle Ben that he was sick and they should haul him
> immediately to the ER while alerting the toxicology and animal venom
> unit—presuming there were such things—that they were going to have a
> major case on their hands.*
>
> *At least, that was what his mind was telling his body he was about to
> do. His body, however, wasn't the least bit interested in cooperating.
> Instead, just when he thought it couldn't hurt any more, it got worse.*
>
> *His legs curled up into a fetal position, and sweat was pouring off
> his body like a sumo wrestler working a Stairmaster. The carpet
> beneath his head was soaked with perspiration, and he was shaking
> uncontrollably, extreme heat and lethal chills taking turns pounding
> through his system. His teeth were chattering, and if he'd been able
> to make it to a mirror, he would have seen that his eyes were sunken,
> his face the color of vanilla pudding.*
>
> ***He made one final effort to stand, but it would have been impossible
> to tell by looking at him, because he didn't budge from the floor.
> Instead he curled up even tighter, his arms clutching around his legs,
> drawing his knees up to just under his chin. His eyes rolled up into
> the top of his head, and the final jolt of pain was too overwhelming
> for him to handle.With a final, low moan, he passed out dead away.**
> Under his lids, his eyes continued to flutter.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Spider-Man - Official Novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/221982.Spider_Man)</sup></sub>

Comment: That makes it yet another movie that would have made no sense if it were set outside the US :P

Comment: @Erik glad someone said it

Comment: @NOP Sounds like you need to re-read Be Nice. Or read it for the first time, maybe.

Comment: i deleted my comment immediately, QPaysTaxes, you are correct, I apologise. I'm just getting very fed up with every subject somehow being shifted into hateful political agenda. It's a question about spiderman, for goodness sake. how is this an invitation to spit on a nation?

Comment: @NOP - Nobody's spitting on America, we're merely commenting on the fact that your health care system appears to benefit everyone but the sick

Comment: btw both comments have been flagged for Be Nice ; p they serve no positive purpose, and are there for spite.

Comment: @Valorum Fair enough, is that the real intent of the question then?  To call out America's "health care system"?

Comment: @NOP - The intent of the question was to ask why he didn't call a doctor or an ambulance. The answer merely happens to be that he was worried about the expense. Without the additional commentary, those living in countries with non-insane healthcare systems might simply not understand that thinking.